# Confused between two option to show the new leave application to review

Tags: wireframe

The module in which I am working in leave module where employee's overall leave balance, leave count with specific leave type would be listed.

In this product mainly 2 type of users are there. 1)Employee 2)Manager
Now my question is about the manager role. I want to put leave confirmation part for the manager. 
I am stuck that where I can give this feature under *My Leave* section?

I found two option but confused that either of which is good according to user prospect. Or please suggest another way to show.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How critical is for the manager to be aware of changes in status of pending leaves? Assuming that the manager will log in to this app and get that information in order to know if he must take action or not.

**Option 1**

Manager sees that he has 2 pending leaves to review, he had seen them yesterday and knows what they are, he had planned to go over them later that day. During lunch he's asked by an employee if he had received his leave request, he opens and sees number changed to 3, he confirms.

**Option 2**

Manager opens the app, then clicks on the list of leaves icon, there is no other indication, but he wants to make sure it was only 2 pending reviews he had to go over. Later that day he is asked about a pending leave filed by an employee, again he opens and clicks on the icon, goes back and enters again and confirms he had received another.

Now take these scenarios to the extremes, 20 pending leaves? 30? How will that impact your design choices? 0 leaves? How is the user sure this is accurate? Are accuracy and immediacy you are designing for?

**EDIT**

Whenever I'm faced with these sort of problems I like to think about the measurements, the data that would indicate the performance of my design solution.

In this case, for example, I can assume that these metrics might be important:

- User Role
- Count of Daily Sessions
- Count of Events per Session
- Ratio of Value Events per Total Events
- Count of Screens per Value Event Session
- Ratio of Value Events per Screen

**If you know which actions will deliver value to the user role:**

- Design a solution that will minimize the count of screens required for that value event.

**If at this point you don't know which actions will deliver value to each user role:**

- Design a solution that lets the user bookmark different reports, this will let you optimize for both user roles and for extreme cases as well such as someone who's manager and also an employee.

These are all alternatives to the icon vs detail view and now you can compare the other options against the same metrics and the solution might be more obvious.

Comment: This is not related to the question or answer. Sorry for that. But out of curiosity I visited your portfolio website and it contains malware. It tries to make you download a .js file. Are you aware of this?

Comment: Oh @RobEarle I am not aware about this...thanks for your information. Let me do something.

Comment: @JasminJavia I was referring to ghislaineguerin.

Comment: @robEarle I was not aware, I'll take a look, thanks!

Comment: @ghislaineguerin yes you are right.. that is why I stuck over here that whether to go for the new screen or to show in the statistics screen itself. But yes notification will be definitely there to notify the employee about new leave application....do you have any other option except these 2?

Comment: @JasminJavia updated my response. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I pretty much agree with the answer posted above by Ghislaine Guerin. But if I had to choose between, I’d go with option 1.